# Text in divs not wrapping

Tags: wordpress, css, word-wrap

In [this page](http://www.moondogacademy.com/application-form/) there are divs (class="controls") which contain input fields and help text enclosed in spans (class="help-block").

An example:

```
<div class="text-line control-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="pdb-email">Email<span class="reqd">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="email" id="pdb-email" type="text" class="required-field regular-text" value="" data-cip-id="pdb-email">
        <span class="help-block">What is your email address? Make sure it's one you actually check please!</span>
    </div>
</div>

.control-label,
table th,
.required-field {
    color: #fff;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

When I resize the screen for mobile, the help text in the spans does not wrap. It is cut off.

How do I get it to wrap?

Other things to know:

1. The relevant html is output from a script (WordPress plugin), I
   can't edit it.
2. I use this same plugin [here](http://bridgeslanguageschool.com/sign-up-form-blsv2018/). The html is the
   same, but I do not have the issue there - it works responsively.
3. Other things I have tried that didn't fix the issue include:

   - `word-wrap: break-word;` at the div and body levels
   - ```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
         .controls {
             max-width: 100%;
             word-wrap: break-word;
         }
     }
     ```

Answer (score 0):

The input tag should not automatically wrap lines, you can use a textarea tag or write a div in a similar style to input, using contentEditable="true"...

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div style="width:100px" contentEditable="true">coding</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @john q.  Actually, the html is all generated by a plugin; I can't change it.  At any rate, the same html is used on another page (different WP site, different theme) and it works responsively.  I've edited the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer here is you need to inspect the HTMl using your browser developer tools to see what CSS rules are affecting the display. This can be complex, especially in responsive displays.

I would look for elements such as labels or help text that are given the "whitespace: nowrap" rule. For instance it looks like the checkbox labels might be pushing the display out.